# Gnuplot: find x value for given y

Tags: gnuplot

I want to do exactly this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165360/pgfplots-and-gnuplot-how-to-add-asymptote-a-xtick-that-isnt-a-number-and-can/165366#165366?newreg=53a345ba2c3f4f4fbf210af7872b1168
but in gnuplot (without the latex stuff).
How can I do that?

This is my plt-file:

```
reset
set xlabel "Distance [kpc]"
set ylabel "Velocity [km/s]"
unset key
set grid
f(x)=m*x+b
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [10:]
set xtics
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set logscale y
fit f(x) "vd.dat" u 1:2 via m, b
plot f(x) lw 2 lc rgb"black"
set term png
set output "~/uni/J2017+0603/J2017+0603_sim_pm_modified.png"
show output
plot f(x) lw 2 lc rgb"black"
```

this is the output:
[plot http://www.ifirn.de/inh/J2017+0603_sim_pm_modified.png](http://www.ifirn.de/inh/J2017+0603_sim_pm_modified.png)

And I want to know, for example, which distance belongs to 87km/s.
And I wnat gnuplot to draw a horizontal line from 87km/s to graph, then vertical down to the x-axis and display the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is the same as described in the link you give: Find the inverse of the function and add the result.

The inverse of your function is `(f(x)-b)/m`. To display the result, use `set arrow`, with the `graph` coordinate system to hit the axes, and `first` to get the coordinates of the actual intersection.

To add the results on the axes, use `set xtics add` and `set ytics add`.

An example script (without the fitting part):

```
reset
set xlabel "Distance (kpc)"
set ylabel "Velocity (km/s)"
set grid

m = 234; b = 1
f(x)=m*x+b
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [10:]
set tics nomirror
set logscale y

set samples 1000
y = 2000.0

set arrow from graph 0, first y to first (y-b)/m,y nohead lt 3
set arrow from first (y-b)/m, y to first (y-b)/m, graph 0 nohead lt 3
set ytics add (sprintf("%.f", y) y)
set xtics add (sprintf("%.2f", (y-b)/m) (y-b)/m)
plot f(x) lw 2 lc rgb"black"
```

[image]