# Gnuplot X value for GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX

Tags: gnuplot

How can I obtain x value for GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX? I have data generated from FLUKA simulation (proton beam hitting water phantom), which I can't describe as a function. I would like to get something like this graph from here: [Gnuplot: find x value for given y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766362/gnuplot-find-x-value-for-given-y) but for the maximum Y value. 
Right now the GNUPLOT code is this:

```
max_y = GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
set label 2 gprintf("Maximum = %g", max_x) at 5, max_y-0.02
```

And the output is this: [image]

As you can see the maximum is around 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stats` command for this kind of analysis. For example, if you have a data file `test.dat` that looks like

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 10
5 5
```

then you can run

```
stats "test.dat"
```

which will set the variable `STATS_pos_max_y` to `4.0`. See `help stats` for a list of available analyses.